# Can an input iterator be dereferenced only on the right-hand sign of an assignment?

Tags: c++, iterator

I have this simple question: in C++ primer 5ed by Lippman chapter 10. "The iterator categories" it is said:

> The Iterator Categories
>
> Input iterators: can read elements in a sequence. An input iterator must provide
>
> - Equality and inequality operators (`==`, `!=`) to compare two iterators
> - Prefix and postfix increment (`++`) to advance the iterator
> - Dereference operator (`*`) to read an element; dereference may appear only on the 
>     right-hand side of an assignment
> - The arrow operator (`->`) as a synonym for `(*it).member`—that is,
>     dereference the iterator and fetch a member from the underlying object.

Did he mean with "Dereference operator (`*`) to read an element; dereference may appear only on the right-hand side of an assignment" : on the "left side of an assignment".??

I am confused about it. Thank you.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The author meant that if you have an input iterator `it`, then you can do:

```
foo = *it;
```

but it's possible you may not be able to do:

```
*it = foo;
```

I.e. you can *read* from an iterator (it's on the right side of an assignment), but there is no guarantee you can *write* to it (it's on the left).

Comment: Ok Okk Thank you! Get it now!

Comment: So you mean `foo` is an object of the underlying type that `it` denotes?

Comment: @ItachiUchiwa - Yes.